# Excel, is it possible to read from a named range similar to a java array? List[0] for example

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, excel, google-sheets

I am struggling to find anything on the internet related to this one.
You can easily name a range in excel and it's treated as an array.
An example would be the average formula. You can feed a list from a named range into the formula.

```
Named Range "list" contains the values:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Named Range "list2" contains the values:
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Currently in excel, this is possible.

```
=Average(Number1,[Number2], ...)
=Average(List1,List2)
```

Would it be possible to do ->

```
Average(list[1],list[6])
```

I want this to make my formulas more simple.

I have a large list of people and instead of doing 
`B1!H4, B1!h5`

I would love to do `N[1], N[2], N[3]`

Thank you all!

Comment: What software do you want to use this? Javascript or java or google spreadsheet? [Edit] your tags

Comment: The question references a java array, the same as a javascript array. Google sheets and excel are interchangeable. My tags are as descriptive as possible for the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

You can use `INDEX()`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(list,1),INDEX(list,6))
```

Where `list` is a named range.